# JUnit Test Fails in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, ant, jenkins-plugins

My JUnit Tests run fine in eclipse and pass locally however in Jenkins my 1st test passes and 2nd one fails and I know why but cant figure out the solution. The Jenkins output says it cant find the element however it is there and I have the proper waits.

Here is the 1st test case that passes.

```
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\eclipse\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");  
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    homeUrl = "https://myadp.adpcorp.com/wps/myportal/main/myADP_new";
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get(homeUrl);
    }

    //Full test
     @Test 
     public void fullTest() throws Exception {

         step01_VerifyHomePage(); 

     }


        // Go to Home page and verify title 
      public void step01_VerifyHomePage() throws Exception {
        driver.getTitle().contains(homeTitle);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
      }




      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }
```

This is the one that fails in Jenkins

```
//Full test
     @Test 
     public void fullTest() throws Exception {

         step02_HoverMyWorkSpace(); 

     }


      public void step02_HoverMyWorkSpace() throws Exception {
          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,20000);
          wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("DivMyWorkList"))));
          if ( driver.findElement(By.id("DivMyWorkList")).isDisplayed()){
              System.out.println("DivMyWorkList Visiable");
          }else{
              System.out.println("DivMyWorkList NOT Visiable");
          }

//        Assert.assertEquals(true, workspace.isDisplayed());
//        Thread.sleep(3000);
      }


      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }
```

Jenkins Output

[image]
The problem i think is that Jenkins cant find the element because the page is not coming up in what ever environment it is using. When I use 
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.id("DivMyWorkList")))); Jenkins test hangs and times out.

If this is the case is there a way around this? It dose not make sense that the 1st test passes by using the same url and the 2nd one uses same url to the exact same page and it can find the title but not the web element.

I am using a VM and created a free style project on it. 
I have been working on this for the past week any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe your jenkins is too small and takes much more time to do any operation. can you add some sleeps or increase the jenkins size?